# how to remove image from placeholder on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css

i already posted this question and still cant seem to get it. whenever i hover for the first time on any of the smaller images the larger image appears on the placeholder and whenever i mouse out of the image the placeholder image is blank which is what i want it to do. however, after only doing it once, whenever i hover over any of the small images it no longer appears it only works the first time please help.

```js
var fullpic = new Array(4);

 for (var i = 0; i < fullpic.length; i++)

   fullpic[i] = new Image(515, 385);

 fullpic[0].src = "http://placehold.it/350x150";
 fullpic[1].src = "http://placehold.it/350x150";
 fullpic[2].src = "http://placehold.it/350x150";
 fullpic[3].src = "http://placehold.it/350x150";


 function displayFull(i) {


   document.getElementById("img-cover").src = fullpic[i].src;
 }

 function hideFull(i) {
   document.getElementById("img-cover").src = fullpic[i].src;
   document.getElementById("img-cover").style.visibility = 'hidden';
 }

 var fullbanner = new Array(4);

 for (var i = 0; i < fullbanner.length; i++)

   fullbanner[i] = new Image(468, 60);

 fullbanner[0].src = "http://placehold.it/350x150";
 fullbanner[1].src = "http://placehold.it/350x150";
 fullbanner[2].src = "http://placehold.it/350x150";
 fullbanner[3].src = "http://placehold.it/350x150";

 var n = 0;

 window.addEventListener("load", showFull, false);

 function showFull() {

   setInterval("showPic()", 3000);


 }

 function showPic() {

   document.getElementById("banner").src = fullbanner[n].src;
   n++;
   if (n > 3)
     n = 0;

 }
```

```css
//CSS
 #banner-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 468px;
  height: 61px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#banner {
  text-align: center;
}
#thumbs {
  width: 425px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#main-img {
  width: 513px;
  height: 385px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#img-cover {
  max-height: 385px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner-wrapper">
</div>

<div id="thumbs">
  <img class="thumb-img" src="http://placehold.it/30x30" onmouseover="displayFull(0)" onmouseout="hideFull(0)">
  <img class="thumb-img" src="http://placehold.it/30x30" onmouseover="displayFull(1)" onmouseout="hideFull(1)">
  <img class="thumb-img" src="http://placehold.it/30x30" onmouseover="displayFull(2)" onmouseout="hideFull(2)">
  <img class="thumb-img" src="http://placehold.it/30x30" onmouseover="displayFull(3)" onmouseout="hideFull(3)">

</div>

<div id="main-img">
  <img id="img-cover" src="">

</div>
```

Comment: [You can now format your code so that it is a runnable snippet, making it easier for us to debug your code](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: In hideFull, you're setting the visibility of the image to hidden. In showFull, you're not resetting the visibility *from* hidden. You need to make it visible again.

Comment: thanks did not realize i had to do that i did

Comment: document.getElementById("img-cover").style.visibility='visible';

Comment: @Web-Student214 Is your issue resolved now?

Answer (score 0):

In your `displayFull(i)` function, set the visibility of the  `#img-cover` to `visible` first. Your code works but the visibility is set to `hidden` so you can't see the result.

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues able to find in your code.

1. In `hideFull()` you are setting `visibility: hidden` and never made it `visible` again
2. Not sure why are you using this `fullbanner` things. Hope it is not related to this question. And it produce errors as `fullbanner[n]` doesn't make sense.

Check below snippet for reference.

```js
var fullpic = new Array(4);

for (var i = 0; i < fullpic.length; i++)
  fullpic[i] = new Image(515, 385);

fullpic[0].src = "http://placehold.it/350x150";
fullpic[1].src = "http://placehold.it/350x150";
fullpic[2].src = "http://placehold.it/350x150";
fullpic[3].src = "http://placehold.it/350x150";


function displayFull(i) {

  document.getElementById("img-cover").src = fullpic[i].src;
}

function hideFull(i) {
  document.getElementById("img-cover").src = "";
  //document.getElementById("img-cover").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

```css
#banner-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 468px;
  height: 61px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#banner {
  text-align: center;
}

#thumbs {
  width: 425px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#main-img {
  width: 513px;
  height: 385px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#img-cover {
  max-height: 385px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner-wrapper">
</div>

<div id="thumbs">
  <img class="thumb-img" src="http://placehold.it/30x30" onmouseover="displayFull(0)" onmouseout="hideFull(0)">
  <img class="thumb-img" src="http://placehold.it/30x30" onmouseover="displayFull(1)" onmouseout="hideFull(1)">
  <img class="thumb-img" src="http://placehold.it/30x30" onmouseover="displayFull(2)" onmouseout="hideFull(2)">
  <img class="thumb-img" src="http://placehold.it/30x30" onmouseover="displayFull(3)" onmouseout="hideFull(3)">

</div>

<div id="main-img">
  <img id="img-cover" src="">
</div>
```